# Passing a list into MySQL stored procedure and check ALL values are present

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a query, where I check the user has ALL the permissions present in a list of perms.

So, it's something like this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT account_id
FROM   pp_acl_user_roles ur, pp_acl_role_permissions rp
JOIN pp_acl_permissions p ON rp.permission_id=p.id
WHERE (
  ur.account_id = '1'
  #check for permission ids OR keys depending on what has been passed in.
  AND ( p.id IN ('read_accounts', 'write_accounts') OR p.key IN ('read_accounts', 'write_accounts') )
  AND ur.role_id = rp.role_id
)
#ensure we have ALL the permissions we asked for, not just some -makes IN() an AND not an OR.
GROUP BY ur.account_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT rp.permission_id) = 2
```

It checks for either a list of `id`s or a list of `keys` for the permissions, so it could be called with either, so this line.

```
p.id IN ('read_accounts', 'write_accounts') OR p.key IN ('read_accounts', 'write_accounts')
```

could be

```
p.id IN (1, 2) OR p.key IN (1, 2)
```

depending on how it's called.

The `HAVING` at the end ensures we matched **all** the items we asked for.

This is fine, but I want to move it to a stored procedure, and I'm hitting a issue.

I had to change `IN` for `FIND_IN_SET` so I could pass a string list into the procedure, but the problem is, I have no way to dynamically calculate how *many* items are in the list, so I can't check they are all present.

Iv'e got this so far...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE has_permission( IN account_id BIGINT, IN permissions TEXT )
BEGIN
  SELECT DISTINCT account_id
  FROM   pp_acl_user_roles ur, pp_acl_role_permissions rp
  JOIN pp_acl_permissions p ON rp.permission_id=p.id
  WHERE (
    ur.account_id = account_id
    #check for permission ids OR keys depending on what has been passed in.
    AND ( FIND_IN_SET(p.id, permissions) OR FIND_IN_SET(p.key, permissions) )
    AND ur.role_id = rp.role_id
  )
  #ensure we have ALL the permissions we asked for, not just some -makes IN() an AND not an OR.
  GROUP BY ur.account_id;
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT rp.permission_id) = ????????????
END //                      
DELIMITER ;
```

But there is no way to calculate the length of the permissions passed in.

I'm sure there is a way to maybe JOIN to the perms table based on the items in the string and ensure we have matches in both tables, but I cant work it out.

Any pointers much appreciated...

Comment: is it sufficient for your front-end to pass a string like `(1,2,3)` and for the stored proc to determine if there is at least 1 that is *not* in that list of perms?

Comment: Yeah, if any of the passed in perms are not assigned to that user that would work....

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've got so far...

Not ideal, but you can work out the length of the items in the string with this..

```
(SELECT LENGTH(permissions) - LENGTH( REPLACE(permissions, ',', '') ) + 1)
```

It basically counts all the commas in the string and uses that as the total number of perms passed in.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE has_permission( IN account_id BIGINT, IN permissions TEXT)
BEGIN
  SELECT DISTINCT account_id
  FROM   pp_acl_user_roles ur, pp_acl_role_permissions rp
  JOIN pp_acl_permissions p ON rp.permission_id=p.id
  WHERE (
    ur.account_id = account_id
    #check for permission ids OR keys depending on what has been passed in.
    AND ( FIND_IN_SET(p.id, permissions) OR FIND_IN_SET(p.key, permissions) )
    AND ur.role_id = rp.role_id

  )
  #ensure we have ALL the permissions we asked for, not just some -makes IN() an AND not an OR.
  GROUP BY ur.account_id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT rp.permission_id) = (SELECT LENGTH(permissions) - LENGTH( REPLACE(permissions, ',', '') ) + 1);
```